# Listing possible permutations of alternating groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was trying to list all possible permutations of an alternating group and I'm a little confused. If I am listing the possible permutations of A10 by disjoint cycle lengths,is (7)(2)(1) in A10? I guess I'm asking whether a single number is considered a cycle of length 2?

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own?

Comment: Well I know (7) would be even and (2) is another of length 2.so I would have 7 2-cycles.But what about the single (1)?

Comment: The cycles $\;(i)\;$, by themselves, denote the identity permutation, and either by the cycle's length criterion or by what I just wrote, they are even permutation...s

Comment: Thank you! Therefore (7)(2)(1) would be even and in A10.

Comment: No then I would have even+odd+even?So (7)(2)(1) is not in A10right?

Comment: Now I'm confusing myself more.

Comment: Can I just ignore the single number and say (7) is 6 2-cycles plus one two cycle? So (7)(2)(1) is odd?